# How can I use exec with cmd in windows?

Tags: php, shell

How can I run this:

```
shell_exec('"C:\Program Files\gammu\bin\gammu.exe" --sendsms TEXT 06706177529 -text "halooo"');
```

With cmd? If i run this in cmd it works very well. So i would like to run it with exec and cmd. I found something like `cmd c/` , but how it works?

Comment: Different questions. The first is what is the problem wit that, the second is: How to use CMD in exec... just the same example code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use [`COM`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php).

```
$shell = new COM("WScript.Shell"); 
$exec = $shell->Run($cmd, 0, false);
```

That's a simple example, if you head over to http://php.net/function.exec and take a look at the comments a few people have posted a solution.

Take a look at this comment http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.exec.php#57538, a nice function is provided to wrap around the above code. I'll paste it here just in case.

```
<?php
define ('EXEC_TMP_DIR', 'C:\tmp');

function windExec($cmd,$mode=''){
    // runs a command line and returns
    // the output even for Wind XP SP2
    // example: $cmd = "fullpath.exe -arg1 -arg2"
    // $outputString = windExec($cmd, "FG");
    // OR windExec($cmd);
    // (no output since it runs in BG by default)
    // for output requires that EXEC_TMP_DIR be defined

    // Setup the command to run from "run"
    $cmdline = "cmd /C $cmd";

    // set-up the output and mode
    if ($mode=='FG'){
        $outputfile = EXEC_TMP_DIR . "\\" . time() . ".txt";
        $cmdline .= " > $outputfile";
        $m = true;
    }
    else $m = false;

    // Make a new instance of the COM object
    $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");

    // Make the command window but dont show it.
    $oExec = $WshShell->Run($cmdline, 0, $m);

    if ($outputfile){
        // Read the tmp file.
        $retStr = file_get_contents($outputfile);
        // Delete the temp_file.
        unlink($outputfile);
    }
    else $retStr = "";

    return $retStr;
}
```